# Why error message "The method getText() is undefined for the type String" is showing?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to open the link in another method, but after opening the browser link is not being opened and while trying to get the motorvehicle variable I am getting an error like "The method getText() is undefined for the type String" and "Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to String".

```
public class ExcelReadData {

    WebDriver driver;
public void driverCall() 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    public void login(String username,String password)

    {
         driver.get("http://kaefer.ccstechnologies.org/#/login");
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='username']")).sendKeys(username);
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).sendKeys(password);
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block primary-button']")).click();
    }
public void  addHireFromMotorVehicleOwn(String motorvehicle)
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='add-vehicle']")).click();//click on add vehicle

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='mat-radio-inner-circle'])[1]")).click();//click on own radio button
        //1st value
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//mat-form-field[@id='vehicleCategoryOwn']")).click();//click on dropdown value
        String motorvehiclename1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//mat-option[@id='Pickup']")).click();//click on pickup from dropdown
        motorvehiclename1.getText()
}}
```

Comment: Am new to selenium, So please help it out to resolve.

Comment: Just going by your code I assume you want to get the text from webelement having xpath `//mat-option[@id='Pickup']`? In which case, you should probably use something like `String motorvehiclename1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//mat-option[@id='Pickup']")).getText();`

Comment: Still am getting the following error"Cannot invoke getText() on the primitive type void"

Comment: Having error on driver also

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
String motorvehiclename1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//matoption[@id='Pickup']")).click();
```

It should be

```
WebElement motorvehiclename1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//matoption[@id='Pickup']"));
```

motorvehiclename1.getText();

As the findElement method returns a webelement and not a string.

Comment: type mismatch: cannot convert from void to WebElement